# Implementing Cloud Code on Open Source Parse Server

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, parse-cloud-code

I am developing an app using the new Parse Server. I have researched quite a bit, but cannot figure this out. I want to run some server side code (Cloud Code) but I cannot figure out how to even create a Cloud Code file using Heroku and Mongo. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: what do you want to achieve

Comment: I want to be able to call a cloud code function. I had this working with the hosted Parse but I'm not sure how to make a cloud code file with the open source Parse Server running on Heroku so that I can call Cloud Code functions from it.

Comment: you just need to mention serverURL and path to your cloud file while setting up parse server and rest everything remains same

Comment: Can you explain to me how to add the path to my cloud code file if I have already set up parse server. Or point me in the direction of any documentation for this. Also, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the root of app create a cloud folder and create a main.js file in that folder and copy the sample contents in the file

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  res.success('Hi');
});
```

Then in your Index.js mention the path of this file in config

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: 'myAppId',
  masterKey:  '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337'  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to find index.js anywhere.

Comment: index.js is just sample name you will have one js file which will bootstrap your parse server check this out https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

Comment: @AjayBeniwal the problem I see here is that you need to deploy / re-deploy your application every time cloud code needs to be changed, any way to create cloud code from the dashboard?

Comment: @AjayBeniwal those of us who deployed directly to Heroku with the "Deploy to Heroku" button don't have this index.js file... Should we create it?

Comment: Ive not followed parse server from long ago now but i remember you have to create the file of own