# How to setup Cloud Coding on Parse Open Server using Heroku

Tags: heroku, cloud, parse-cloud-code, countdowntimer, parse-server

I have looked everywhere but cannot seem to figure out how to setup cloud coding on the Parse Open Server using Heroku.

I see this link which tells me what to put in the Index.js and Main.js file: [Implementing Cloud Code on Open Source Parse Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738765/implementing-cloud-code-on-open-source-parse-server?answertab=active#tab-top). However, I cannot seem to find those files. Nor can I find the "cloud" folder.
How do I find the cloud folder?

I created the Parse Server on MongoDB using the "Deploy to Heroku" link on this page: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example. After creating my application by filling out all the information, I ran the command `heroku git:clone -a yourAppName` to clone the application files. However, when I use the command I obtain a empty repository and get the following message in my terminal:

```
Cloning into 'hyv3-moja'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

So, how/where do I find the cloud folder with main.js? Did I miss any step in creating the Parse Server?

I also tried using the Parse Command Line. However, when I try to use the `parse new` command, it requires me to login to a Parse account. However, since Parse is going down, they are not accepting new accounts and I did not have an account before. Regardless, this seems like a deadend.

So can someone please explain to me how to set up Cloud Code?? I want to create a code that decrements a column in the database every second so it operates like a timer. Basically, I want my application to create objects on the database that last a certain amount of time chosen by the user. For this example, ill say 24 hours. So from the moment it is created, I want to decrement those 24 hours in the database. That way when a user of my application clicks to view the object, I translate the time remaining from the database and just output that value to the user to show how much time is remaining for the life of the object.